# Ubuntu 16.04 outgoing requests issue on Ethernet connection

Tags: networking, 16.04, internet

I have Ubuntu Mate 16.04.
I have internet connection through Ethernet cable. Cable is okay, it worked for previous ubuntu version, it still works for windows.

However, on this particular system, some sites (example being coursera.org) are working slow and unreliably, the defining feature of such sites is that they are very intricate and involve some sort of login and data sending. Chromium just shows "uploading 0%" in the status messages at the bottom.

On other sites there are problems with message sending, say a really short message can be sent no problem, but if a message is over 200 characters it just keeps showing "sending" or "uploading" till site scripts give up.

When I use network applet to reconnect, or replug the cable the error message pops up: `Active connection removed before it was initialized`.
However, sometimes this action does temporarily fix things and I become able to load several pages from the site.

Also, the sites in question are not obscure pages on low-cost servers, they're established media portals which wouldn't be what they are if they'd experience server-side problems of that frequency.

Here is `ifconfig` output. I'm confused about ipv6 addresses, currently, settings are to ignore ipv6 but they are still there:

```
enp7s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:d4:35:f3:87:c7  
          inet addr:10.20.4.24  Bcast:10.20.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: 2a00:f480:4:229:76d4:35ff:fef3:87c7/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::76d4:35ff:fef3:87c7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5063 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4121 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2975637 (2.9 MB)  TX bytes:614716 (614.7 KB)
```

How could this problem be diagnosed further?

---

Using [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/333430/521426) answer I get some more info.
`lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -i ethernet`. The card is:

```
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [1028:0652]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
08:00.0 3D controller [0302]: irrelevant stuff
```

How could this problem be diagnosed further?

Comment: Which ethernet model and what driver is loading? To prevent ipv6 use there's a kernel switch you need to put into /etc/default/grub, followed by update-grub.

Comment: It's some Realtec thing, RTL8101/2/6E PCI, I guess. And the driver is  r8169.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/819376/ethernet-connection-issues-on-ubuntu-16-04?rq=1