# Ethernet stops working repeatedly?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have faced this problem of Ethernet connection failure earlier. After trying various solutions, it finally stated working. The last one was this [youtube one](https://www.evernote.com/client/web?_sourcePage=V5EGUrsQal_iMUD9T65RG_YvRLZ-1eYO3fqfqRu0fynRL_1nukNa4gH1t86pc1SP&__fp=ucBK5tw8ySs3yWPvuidLz-TPR6I9Jhx8&hpts=1567058123076&showSwitchService=true&usernameImmutable=false&login=&login=Sign+in&login=true&hptsh=3Sduo8c1k%2Fpnp6QSuWnbGe7E%2BhY%3D).  I agree it was not the best way to fix such a problem.
So I have gone through [this landmark question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205). Here is the 
  [wireless info paste.ubuntu.com](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/g8rjf9mD6y/).
It seems to have collected more than I could have thought of.
I have gone through the following questions

[Ethernet connection Issues on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819376/ethernet-connection-issues-on-ubuntu-16-04) (Ethernet controller is different than mine, So I don't think so the solution would help.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really just a workaround solution inspired by that [youtube link](https://www.evernote.com/client/web?_sourcePage=V5EGUrsQal_iMUD9T65RG_YvRLZ-1eYO3fqfqRu0fynRL_1nukNa4gH1t86pc1SP&__fp=ucBK5tw8ySs3yWPvuidLz-TPR6I9Jhx8&hpts=1567058123076&showSwitchService=true&usernameImmutable=false&login=&login=Sign+in&login=true&hptsh=3Sduo8c1k%2Fpnp6QSuWnbGe7E%2BhY%3D). It is just something to try out if you are hard-pressed for time. (Acknowledgements to my friend Surender.)
So, I typed in

> sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf

and edited the resulting file from this

```
#nameserver 10.200.1.11
nameserver 10.200.1.11
nameserver 10.200.1.11
nameserver 10.200.1.11
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

To this

```
#nameserver 10.200.1.11
#nameserver 10.200.1.11
#nameserver 10.200.1.11
#nameserver 10.200.1.11
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
#nameserver 127.0.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

After this, I entered

> sudo service network-manager restart

and voila Internet works. Now, I really don't think so my answer is right. I mean it's obvious, isn't it? I am editing a file which has a line

> ## DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

Obviously, this will fail again when I restart my computer. So, I think I need to do something to fix this resolvconf (note the missing "." it is not resolv.conf) or glibc. Maybe a good starting point would be [resolvconf man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/resolvconf.8.html). I think this question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128220/how-do-i-set-my-dns-when-resolv-conf-is-being-overwritten)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174349/what-overwrites-etc-resolv-conf-on-every-boot